# transferring images between two iphones using gestures

Tags: iphone, sdk, gestures

I'm wondering if it would be possible at all to transfer data between two different iphones using gestures on one iphone? For instance, flick an image on iphone A and it would show up on iphone B.

I realize this would require some sort of communication channel between the two iphones (may be bluetooth?). Assuming such a communication channel has been established, is it possible? I'm looking for ideas from the community on how this can be accomplished if it is possible.

Thanks! - Azeem

Comment: Like Mover? http://infinite-labs.net/mover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [Bump API](http://bu.mp/api.html).  Sure the gesture would be knocking the two devices together, but it looks really easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just open a connection between the devices ([GameKit](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) could provide the peer-to-peer connectivity). Create a method that sends content, then call that method when you detect the  gesture that you'd like to use.

You'll obviously need to have views that display the content that you'd like to send, but you can easily detect that a user has initiated a touch within one of your views in order to determine which content to actually send.